# Entity Framework, conditional load of entity / left outer join

Tags: entity-framework, linq, left-join

I have a problem with querying a core table with conditional joining of sub tables. Let's say there are two tables:

```
Person: 
Id UniqueIdentifier
AddressId UniqueIdentifier
Name nvarcharmax
Deleted bit

PersonAddress:
Id UniqueIdentifier
AddressLine nvarcharmax
Deleted bit
```

Now I need a query that's going to retrieve a Person and PersonAddress. If PersonAddress.Deleted == true the query should still retrieve Person, with the PersonAddress entity being null.

I've tried multiple approaches, but never got it to work. Inner joins return total null if PersonAddress.Deleted == true, left outer joins always return PersonAddress even if Deleted == 1.

Example:

```
var result = 

  from person in Context.Persons.Include(i=>i.PersonAddresses)
  from address in Context.PersonAddresses.Where(w=>!w.Deleted)
where
  person.AddressId == address.Id
  && !person.Deleted
  &&.... what?
```

doing the syntax of join on into forces me to create an ad-hoc entity and abandon all existing mappings which I really don't want. I can always do lazy load or just trim the unneeded entities from the core one, but that's just nasty, ugly and wrong :)

In t-sql this is a trivial query but EF is doing my head in

Comment: Edit your question and post real classes with navigation properties.